# How to Apply a Function to all of the Children in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having an incredibly hard time with recursive data types in Haskell. I am trying some practice problems before I do the actual assignment, but I am finding one problem that is continuously keeping me from figuring out some of these problems.
We have

```
data Person = MakePerson String [Person]
```

Say I want to count all of the number of people in

```
charles = MakePerson "Charles" [MakePerson "Charlotte" [], 
MakePerson "Phil" [MakePerson "Tom" []]]
```

This is what I have so far

```
countPeople :: Person -> Int
countPeople (MakePerson a b)
    | b == [] = 1
    | otherwise = 1 + countPeople (head b)
```

I however don't know how to apply this function to every single element in the list of people, only to the head of the list. I was thinking about using map, but I'm not 100% sure how to use it to apply the function to all of the elements of the list and return a sum.

Comment: FYI: There is never a good reason to use “(== [])”. Never. Always pattern match on “[]” directly or use “null” if you actually need a “Bool”. “(==)” induces an “Eq” constraint, so e.g “[not] == []” is a compile error, not “False”, because there is no “Eq (Bool -> Bool)”. It makes no difference here because “Eq Int”, but it’s a bad habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about this as getting the count of each child, summing those together, and adding one.

```
countChildren :: Person -> Int
countChildren (MakePerson _ []) = 1  -- a person with no children
countChildren (MakePerson _ xs) = 1 + sum (map countChildren xs)
```

Comment: What goes wrong if you omit the "person with no children" clause?

Comment: @DanielWagner Hrm, actually nothing (since `map _ [] = []` and `sum (map _ []) = 0`), though I still prefer the explicit base case.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
```

For example, `sum [1,2,3] = 6`.

You can then use this to accumulate your list together (`sum` it after `map`ing `countPeople` over it).

Here's a more general guide that I found helpful. http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Comment: FYI, bird style code blocks don't work on SO - you just have to bite the bullet and indent. :)

Comment: @Alec There's no bullet-biting about this, just use ctrl+k.

Comment: I tried doing something something similar 
royaltyCount :: Royalty -> Int
royaltyCount (MakeRoyalty name royalList)
    | royalList == [] = 1
    | otherwise = sum map royaltyCount royalList

This however doesn't work, so there is something I am still missing here.

Comment: @DrJessop just your order of operations. Function application associates left, so `sum map f xs` tries to do `sum map`, which of course fails (since `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, and `sum` is expecting a value of type `Num a => [a]`)